# Is it a good practice to cancel a HTTP request with another request?

Tags: http-request

Consider we have an HTTP server and there are many concurrent clients making HTTP requests to this server.

The responses are adequately big to be considered.

User may send requests on the trot, with different request bodies. Once a new request has been made, former requests made by same user become obsolete.

In this type of situation, looking from client aspect, that may not be an issue. However, in server-side, it will make considerable amount of CPU time steal. If there is no way to do further processing relied upon former requests that came from same users, what to do? Here are some workarounds I thought:

- to make a new HTTP request from client in order to cancel the process in server-side (via **different** port)
- checking client if incoming request is a further request (over *IPv4* or *MAC* address, is there a popular way to conduct this?)

That being said, please let the task being done by server upon HTTP requests is **nonatomic** (otherwise I think it would be a maze, because as I know a block-closure passed to some dispatch authority will be executed, ultimately).

This was actually a [request-response pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request%E2%80%93response) question because it is not limited to use HTTP. Sadly, there was no tag named request-response.

Thank you.

Comment: In short, one HTTP request cannot interfere with another.

Comment: @e4c5 If there is another listening port on the server, it can.

Comment: really? how does it do that?

Comment: @e4c5 what would the problem be?

Comment: Well you said it can be done by listening in on another port so I am asking how exactly that works

Comment: @e4c5 It works in node.js using hapi.js module, ports at 8000 and 9000. Also they both receive HTTP requests incoming from another device in LAN (it's my phone).